# Tensorboard. Profile. Month in trace_viewer

Tags: profiling, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I am using Tensorboard to profile some training code. As I can see on [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMc9F.png) in the official [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler) the time line in Trace View should be measured in ms. In my case ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Uth.png)), I have month while I ran a sample training for 2 minutes total. Why it is happen?

Comment: Could you please refer to this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d) and time can be selected from the time axis. See this [screenshot](http://screenshot.googleplex.com/99sSpwXrTbNxnzt) mentioned in the article given.Thanks